# How to edit overrideModeDefault in applicationhost.config for section using appcmd

Tags: powershell

I am trying to edit the applicationhost.config using powershell.

I notice in IIS that the setting gets changed but the actual applicationHost.config does not have the overrideModeDefault overriden for windowsAuthentication. I need to set it to ALLOW

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:windowsAuthentication /enabled:true /commit:apphost
```

Is there anyway this can be achieved using powershell appcmd?

Comment: appcmd.exe and Powershell scripting are 2 distinct things. One is an executable and one is a scripting environment. If you can post the entire tree in your XML where this key is located I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this my using

```
unlock config C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe section:system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication
```

Hope this helps others